# Change the color of if,else,while,for,foreach

Tags: php, themes, sublimetext3

Hi i want to change the color of instructions :

```
if,else,while,for,foreach,endif..
```

In my monokai sublime color sheme, but i can't find the dict key associated to theses instructions.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
<dict>
  <key>name</key>
  <string>Keyword</string>
  <key>scope</key>
  <string>keyword</string>
  <key>settings</key>
  <dict>
    <key>foreground</key>
    <string>#ff005e</string>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

Or

```
<dict>
  <key>name</key>
  <string>Tag name</string>
  <key>scope</key>
  <string>entity.name.tag</string>
  <key>settings</key>
  <dict>
    <key>fontStyle</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>foreground</key>
    <string>#ff005e</string>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

hope this helped.

Comment: No because i want to make a difference between tags name ex differentiate  "if" and  "=>"